# Batch insert/update calls with a list parameter into a single operation/request to database in Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, dapper

Based off this code on Dapper's github page, I created a bulk insert statement. 
[image]

Dapper split up the query into multiple individual SQL insert statements (as seen in SQL profiler).

Is it possible to instruct it to change multiple operations into a single operation to reduce the number of DB trips without having to manually create multiple insert statements like below?

```
insert into test (a,b) values (b,c);
insert into test (a,b) values (d,e);
insert into test (a,b) values (f,g);
```

Comment: yes, use SqlBulkCopy in C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to instruct it to change multiple operations into a single operation

No

There is generally two answer to allow perform bulk operations:

### SqlBulkCopy

As @iSR5 answered in the comment section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy

You will not find anything faster than this.

### Dapper Plus

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Dapper Plus](http://dapper-plus.net/)

This project is not free but offers all bulk operations:

- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

(Use under the hood `SqlBulkCopy`)

And some more options such as outputting identity values:

```
// CONFIGURE & MAP entity
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Order>()
                 .Table("Orders")
                 .Identity(x => x.ID);

// CHAIN & SAVE entity
connection.BulkInsert(orders)
          .AlsoInsert(order => order.Items);
          .Include(x => x.ThenMerge(order => order.Invoice)
                         .AlsoMerge(invoice => invoice.Items))
          .AlsoMerge(x => x.ShippingAddress);
```

**EDIT:** answer comment

> SqlBulkCopy can only be used with MS SQL Server though. Isn't it?

Exactly, SqlBulkCopy is only compatible with SQL Server. Our library supports multiple providers:

- SQL Server
- SQL Compact
- Oracle
- MySql
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Firebird

Comment: SqlBulkCopy can only be used with MS SQL Server though. Isn't it?